# wrong column type Found: image, expected: longblob in mssql server

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

hai i am using spring jpa hibernate with ms sql server as database.I am encountered the error as Found: image, expected: longblob.In my entity class i have the following code

```
@Lob
private byte[] files;
```

In database script 
FILES  image;

the stack trace for the above exception is

```
Found: image, expected: longblob
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1336)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
```

Comment: can you please add full stack of exception.